# Tool to log (OS) events during EJB tests (analyze PC crash)

Tags: java, crash, ejb

I have some issues with my PC and don't know what else to check or look for.
If the tags or description are off, feel free to edit/comment.

Basically the question is: Do you know of any tool that I could run during reproduction of the test, which logs frequently and might provide a hint on what's going on?

If anyone already has a clue of what could cause the problem, that would be great as well.

So here's the problem:

I have a running JBoss 4.2.3.GA server application which provides some EJBs with remote interfaces. Those EJBs write or read stuff to/from the database but that doesn't seem to matter since I also had methods that just did a `System.out.println(...)`  and nothing more.

Now I run a test client from the console which basically just "remotely" calls one of those EJB methods in a loop (to take some timings etc.).

So far nothing too unorthodox should be done, it's basically just a bunch of remote EJB calls.

However, during the execution of the loop the computer freezes completely (keyboard doesn't respond as well, e.g. num-lock key) - the only thing that changes is the blinking cursor. :)

Unfortunately I didn't manage to find a reason for this and since I often do my tests from eclipse I'd like to not have that happen too often (workspace crashes etc.)

Here's what I tried so far:

- Numerous hardware tests including Lenovo PC Doctor (it's a Lenovo PC) - all succeeded, so i seems like there's no hardware problem
- Use different JDK versions: 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.7.0 - all crashed
- JRockit JVM (Java 6) - crashed as well
- make Java cause 100% CPU load (10 thread running constantly on 4 cores) - succeeded/no error
- allocate as much memory as the JVM would allow me - succeeded
- run the tests on other computers - succeeded, except one that has the same hardware and similar software setup
- Windows logs don't provide a hint (except "system was not shut down correctly" ... well that helps :) )

After all these tests I assume it might be a problem with the system configuration (drivers etc.) but I don't know how to track that (and I can't just use brute force due to the massive time requirements).

So, did anyone experience similar problems?

Do you know of any tool that I might use to log what the system does and preferably get a log right before the crash?

Thanks in advance,

Thomas